# Are there any collections in the NBG set theory that are neither classes nor sets?

Tags: set-theory

Just as proper classes in ZFC are defined as collections which don't fulfill the ZFC set axioms, are there any objects which don't fulfill not only the set, but also the NBG class axioms?

How are they called?

Answer (score 1):

In ZFC, proper classes are collections *definable* in ZFC (by some formula of the language of set theory) which are not sets — not because they "don't fulfill the axioms", but because their existence doesn't follow from the axioms. In ZFC, the possible values of variables are sets, and only sets. In NGB and Morse-Kelley (MK) set theory, variables range over both sets and classes. Any class definable by a formula (and, in NGB, subject to restrictions) can be among the possible values of variables.

A model of NGB or MK will contain two sorts of entities: sets, and proper classes. There may well be further proper classes which exist *in a larger universe than the model*, which are subclasses of the model's universe, but which are not *in the model itself*. However, the model has no way of speaking of them: they aren't definable by a set comprehension (set builder) expression of the kind that the theory allows. I don't think there is a name for such classes — one seldom meets any.

Comment: What does "not follow from the axioms" exactly mean?

Comment: A ZFC class $C$ is defined by a formula $\phi(x)$, namely,  $C = \{x\mid \phi(x)\}$ It follows from the axioms of ZFC that $C$ is a set iff $ZFC \vdash \exists y\, y = \{x\mid \phi(x)\}$. That is, $ZFC \vdash \exists y\forall x\,[ x\in y = \phi(x)]$. I.e. that is a theorem of ZFC. It *does not follow from the axioms" of ZFC iff that is not a theorem of ZFC.

Comment: What does ${\exists}yy$ mean?

Comment: Following your terminology, we have in ZFC that a class $C$ is a set iff there is some ordinal $\alpha$ such that $\operatorname{rk}(x) < \alpha$ for all $x \in C$. So the comment about classes that are not sets seems rather strange... There may very well be sets, whose existence isn't provable in ZFC, but in any (transitive) model these are classes iff they are sets.

Comment: @Stefan The definition is Jech's (3rd Millenium Edition): e.g. p. 182 — "If $C$ is a class $\{x : φ(x)\}$ then $C^M$ denotes the class $\{x : φ^M(x)\}$".